# How to iterate and retrieve from YAML _data in Jekyll?

Tags: arrays, ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to build a Jekyll blog. But I never used YAML before and I'm going mad with the logic of this thing.

First I wrote a YAML file in `_data/authors.yml` with a list of authors and their respective meta-info:

```
- authors:
    - user: andre
      name: Andre Santos
      site: http://test.dev
      email: andre@test.dev

    - user: john
      name: John Doe
      site:
      email: john.doe@test.dev
```

Now I want to do two very simple things: first, to iterate over all authors, displaying some info about them:

```
{% for list in site.data.authors %}
   {% for author in list %}
      {{ author.user }} - {{ author.user.name }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it shows nothing!

Now in some other part of the code I just want to retrieve info from a specific user:

```
{% assign the_user = site.data.authors.authors[post.username] %}
{{ the_user.name }}
```

And, once again it shows nothing! I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I tried lots of other solutions, iterations, but I can't make heads or tails about how to iterate YAML files, and I don't know Ruby so most of the solutions I found in this site don't work for me when I adapt them into Jekyll + Liquid.

What am I doing wrong? How to access those variables?

Comment: Changing the first line of your YAML file to `authors:` and using the username as the key for each author would fix it. Otherwise you have an object in an array, while you are accessing the author as if it was a object within an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

After some long deliberation, I got a very simple solution, based on 2 steps: change from YAML to JSON, and then understanding Jekyll returns a Ruby Hash instead of an array.

So, the final file, `authors.json`:

```
{
   "andre": {
       "name": "Andre Santos",
       "site": "http://test.dev",
       "email": "andre@test.dev"
   },
   "john": {
       "name": "John Doe",
       "site": "",
       "email": "john.doe@test.dev"
   }
}
```

Now that the file is corrected, let's take care of selecting one of its items and showing it.

```
{{ site.data.authors[post.author].name }}
```

If `post.author = "andre"`, the template will return `Andre Santos`. First problem, solved!

Now, Jekyll is quite dumb and still doesn't works fine with JSON. No matter what we do, it will iterate poorly with it. So, let's analyse the following situation:

In a test, I decided to dump the iteration. So:

```
{% for author in site.data.author %}
    {{ author }}
    ----
{% endfor %}
```

It produces the following result:

```
 andre{"name"=>"Andre Santos", "site"=>"test.dev";, "email"=>"andre@test.dev"} ---- 
 john{"name"=>"John Doe", "site"=>nil, "email"=>"john.doe@test.dev"} ----
```

This result shows Jekyll isn't producing an array, but a Hash (notice the => symbol). So, let's try to deal with it as a Hash. If I try to print `{{ author[0]` it will show `andre` and `john`. Excellent! So, the next part of the Hash (the metadata) is, in fact author[1].

The final code to display the info:

```
{% for author in site.data.authors %}
    Username: {{ author[0] }}
    Full Name: {{ author[1]["name"] }}
    {% if author[1]["site"] != "" %}
        Site: {{ author[1]["site"] }}
    {% endif %}
    E-Mail: {{ author[1]["email"] }}
    -----
{% endfor %}
```

And the result:

```
 Username: andre
 Full Name: Andre Santos
 Site: http://test.dev
 E-Mail: andre@test.dev
 ----
 Username: john
 Full Name: John Doe
 E-Mail: john.doe@test.dev
 ----
```

Ta da!

So, to wrap it up: drop YAML and use JSON, get info from a specific part of the JSON using simple dot notation and key. When using `for`, deal with it as a Hash. The code becomes a little harder to deal with, but at least it's working as I wanted. In the future, if Jekyll takes JSON a little more seriously, it will probably let us iterate it a little easier.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your data file :

```
- user: andre
  name: Andre Santos
  site: http://test.dev
  email: andre@test.dev

- user: john
  name: John Doe
  site:
  email: john.doe@test.dev
```

Now you can get your datas like this :

```
<ul>
{% for author in site.data.authors %}
  <li>{{ author.user }} - {{ author.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Or like this :

```
{% assign the_user = site.data.authors | where: "user", post.username | first %}
{{ the_user.name }}
```

Comment: The for didn't work. It only prints - -, so it isn't showing the author.user neither the author.user.name. Jekyll is so wacky.